# installation error: Content path '/sitecore/Commerce/Commerce Control Panel' already exists

Tags: sitecore-commerce, sitecore-install-framework

I am getting the below error while trying to install Sitecore Experience Commerce 9.0 Update 2:

[image]

```
[--------------------------- EnsureSyncDefaultContentPaths : EnsureSyncDefaultContentPaths ---------------------------]
Ensure/Sync default content paths for: AdventureWorksAuthoring
Checking if https://localhost:5005/commerceops/CheckCommandStatus(taskId=2655) has completed ...
Ensure/Sync default content paths for environment AdventureWorksAuthoring failed, please check Engine service logs for
ore info.
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : ScriptHalted
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\Public\Install-SitecoreConfiguration.ps1:253
char:21
+                     & $entry.Task.Command @paramSet | Out-Default
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration
```

The service logs in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CommerceShops_Sc9\wwwroot\logs points to:

> ERROR CtxMsg.Error.ContentPathAlreadyExists: Text=Content path
>   '/sitecore/Commerce/Commerce Control Panel' already exists.

I have also tried the below steps to resolve the error but still unable to.

- Added the binding in IIS for the Sitecore website(sxp9u2.sc) and sxa,storefront.com with https(443).
- Added the above urls with http and https in the *AllowedOrigins* Property of the *config.json* for the below files.
  C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CommerceAuthoring_Sc9\wwwroot
  C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CommerceMinions_Sc9\wwwroot
  C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CommerceOps_Sc9\wwwroot
  C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CommerceShops_Sc9\wwwroot
- Verified $SiteHostHeaderName = "sxa.storefront.com" in the install ps1(Deploy-Sitecore-Commerce.ps1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the below steps to verify and fix the error

1. Make sure the binding in IIS for the Sitecore website(sxp9u2.sc) and sxa,storefront.com with https(443).
   **Note**: By default during Installation these binding should have got added and if they are not then you should add it.
2. Make sure the above urls with http and https in the AllowedOrigins Property of the **config.json** for the below files.
   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CommerceAuthoring_Sc9\wwwroot\ C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CommerceMinions_Sc9\wwwroot\ C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CommerceOps_Sc9\wwwroot\ C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CommerceShops_Sc9\wwwroot\
3. Make sure you have *$**SiteHostHeaderName** = "sxa.storefront.com"* in the install ps1(*Deploy-Sitecore-Commerce.ps1*)
4. Added the ConnectionString in **appsettings.json** (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SitecoreIdentityServer\wwwroot) with "*User Id*", "*Password*" and removed "*Integrated Security*". Make sure the user id have all the required permission on the SQL server database.
   **Note** With the default ConnectionString my connection to the SQL was not working so I modified it here with the one than works.
5. Modified the app pool Identity to **LocalSystem** as the default CSFRuntimeUser was not working.

Comment: For which site did you modify the app pool identity?

Answer (score 1):

If you are installing sitecore commerce for the first time on the sitecore instance, this issue will less likely to happen.This issue happens mostly in the scenario where 
the installation is halted for any other errors occurred and run a re installation of the sitecore commerce.

To fix this issue here is what i needed to do

1. Added https binding to the sitecore instance i am running the commerce installation.(https://local.sitecore902 for example).
2. Remove all the sitecore commerce related folders in sitecore.
3. Delete all the sitecore related web sites(Ops,Minions,Shops,Aiuthoring,Bizfx and 
   identity server)
4. remove the databases installed in previous installation(
   SitecoreCommerce9_Global and SitecoreCommerce9_SharedEnvironments)
5. Remove all the solr cores of sitecore commerce(CustomersScope,CatalogItemsScope,OrdersScope)
6. Delete the certificates(local.storefront)
7. Rerun the sitecore commerce installation now.It should go through.

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR CtxMsg.Error.ContentPathAlreadyExists: Text=Content path
> '/sitecore/Commerce/Commerce Control Panel' already exists.

This means the Sitecore content for the environment is already synced with SC databases.

The following worked for me:

1. Run the Clean Environment command for the environment from Postman
2. Flush Redis cache
3. Run the script again